# Is there a way to check AD group membership for a computer?

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, active-directory-group

I am trying to check computer group membership through Powershell. I want to be able to specify a certain computer name and find which groups that computer is in but from a Powershell script. I am planning on running the script on a computer, grabbing the hostname, and then printing out what AD groups that computer is in. Is there an easy way to do this?

EDIT:
So the plan here is to have a computer check to see what groups it is in, then assign a printer based on which group it is in. We have many printers that only 3 to 4 people use but due to the spread out nature of the users cannot downsize the amount of printers. I was looking at group policy but did not want to create 20 different GPOs. I wanted to do this with a logon/startup script. I'm not sure if this is doable or feasible.

Edit #2:
This edit it really late to the party but I figured if anyone found this it could help. We ended up using item level targeting on User>Preferences>Control Panel>Printers objects. We made an account in AD for each group of users needing access to the printers. This worked although it did create a long logon process for the first logon of the computer. We also enabled Point-to-Print restrictions so the drivers were loaded from the servers quietly.

Comment: What is your environment like? Do you have a 2008R2 server that you can run it on? Do you have the Quest AD cmdlets installed? Is there a specific reason that you want to run it on the local machine rather than simply querying AD from one machine?

Comment: It is Server 2008 R2 and the idea behind it was to see what group the computer is in and then assign a printer based on that group

Comment: @user1470158 I suugest to use native gpo to do this job: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb310732.aspx

Comment: If you are assigning printers based on group membership then I would expect GPO to be the best solution as well.

Comment: I was thinking group policy as well but we have close to twenty different groups for printers and didn't think that having twenty group policy objects just for printers would be worth it. The other catch is that it's about three users per group so those objects wouldn't be affecting many people. I'm sort of new to the whole production space for AD and GPO and am not familiar with best practices.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will give you the group membership (group names) of the local computer (requires powershell 2.0):

```
([adsisearcher]"(&(objectCategory=computer)(cn=$env:COMPUTERNAME))").FindOne().Properties.memberof -replace '^CN=([^,]+).+$','$1'
```

Comment: I tried this on a client and it returned nothing. I tried adding this to a variable and echoing the variable and it still returned nothing. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: What happens if you remove everything after the findone() method, any output?

Comment: Still nothing, although I found that using 'Get-ADComputer "TestClient" -Properties * | Select-Object MemberOf' got me closer to the groups. I feel as if I should reword my question to describe what I am attempting.

Comment: You could use the AD module but this requires you to load it on any client, it can slow down your login time. The adsisearcher works natively in v2 so I suggest you find out why it doesn't work if you're going to do that in login script.

Comment: I may have found why it doesn't work, The samaccountname requires the dollar sign at the end of the computer name. That said it worked for me without it. Try to add an escaped dollar sign at the end of the computer name: (samaccountname=$env:COMPUTERNAME`$)

Comment: Updated my answer, replaced samaccountname with cn, give it a try.

Comment: That did indeed work, thank you so much. Do you know if there is a way to incorporate this into a script that assigns printers based on the groups?

Comment: Sure, assign the one-liner to a variable, $groups, and test if the group name in question exists:  if($groups -contains 'groupname') { ...assign printer code...}

Answer (score 3):

Apologies if I'm a bit late to the party on this but I needed to find a computer's group membership as well.  After a lot of trial and error, this worked for me.

```
Get-ADComputer "mycomp" -Properties MemberOf | %{if ($_.MemberOf -like "*group name*") {Write-Host "found"} }
```

I noticed that if the string comparison is on a separate line, I needed to do the following

```
$g=Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "CN=myADgroup,OU=myOU,DC=corp,DC=com" -server corp.com
foreach($mbr in $g) {if($name.MemberOf -like "*mycomp*" -eq $true) {Write-Host "found"}}
```

Not sure but I imagine that testing the computer might be faster and easier than testing the group depending on the number of members.

Answer (score 2):

> try running gpresult /V and check under "security GROUPS"

You can also try `gpresult /scope computer /v` under a command prompt (elevated to admin) for more specific results

Answer (score 2):

the gpresult method seems to be the only way I can find that is accurate. Querying AD is not accurate since the computer may have been added to groups but not rebooted. I am sure someone could condense this but it worked well enough for what I needed to see.

```
# Get all active domain servers
$staledate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {(OperatingSystem -Like "*Server*") -and (Enabled -eq $True) -and (LastLogonDate -ge $staledate) -and (Modified -ge $staledate) -and (PasswordLastSet -ge $staledate) -and (whenChanged -ge $staledate) -and (Name -notlike "PHXVSSA101A")} | Select name -expandproperty name
$computers = $computers | Where {(Resolve-DNSName $_.name -ea 0) -and (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.Name -Count 1 -ea 0)} | Sort
# Loop through all active domain servers
Foreach ($computer in $computers)
{
# Pull the gpresult for the current server
$Lines = gpresult /s $computer /v /SCOPE COMPUTER
# Initialize arrays
$cgroups = @()
$dgroups = @()
# Out equals false by default
$Out = $False
# Define start and end lines for the section we want
$start = "The computer is a part of the following security groups"
$end = "Resultant Set Of Policies for Computer"
# Loop through the gpresult output looking for the computer security group section
ForEach ($Line In $Lines)
{
If ($Line -match $start) {$Out = $True}
If ($Out -eq $True) {$cgroups += $Line}
If ($Line -match $end) {Break}
}
# Loop through all the gathered groups and check for Active Directory groups
ForEach ($group in $cgroups)
{
Try {
$check = Get-ADgroup $group -ErrorAction Stop
If ($check) {
$dgroups += $group
}
}
Catch {}
}
# Output server name and any Active Directory groups it is in
$computer
$dgroups
# End of computers loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres an LDAP query to find if a computer is in a group recursively:

```
(((objectClass=computer)(sAMAccountName=COMPUTERNAME$))(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=DistinguishedNameOfGroup))
```

More info: http://justanotheritblog.co.uk/2016/01/27/recursively-check-if-a-usercomputer-is-a-member-of-an-ad-group-with-powershell-2-0/

Answer (score 0):

To check the computer's own view of group membership, you can run:

```
(New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal("$env:computername$")).IsInRole('Example Group')
True
```

Taking the computer out of `Example Group` doesn't affect the output of the above until the computer is rebooted.

Comment: Thought I had a winner here. However, the computer actually seems to reflect the group membership change frequently, without a reboot. However, `gpupdate` and `gpresult` still do not reflect the change. One way to reproduce my results is by simply locking and unlocking the computer. This will cause this command to reflect the group membership change.

Answer (score -1):

Try this DOS Command, this will return all the local groups this computer belong to :

```
net localgroup
```

Comment: That lists the local groups, not the group membership of the computer account.