# Determine if computer is in AD group

Tags: vb.net

I am looking to determine if a computer is a member of an AD group or even getting all computers that are members of an AD group using VB.net.  I have found several examples for checking to see if a user is a member of a group but none for checking for computers.  I was hoping to convert this function to search for a computer in the group but I was unsuccessful.  Any assistance would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
Function IsInGroup(GroupName) As Boolean
    Dim MyIdentity As System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
    Dim MyPrincipal As System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal = New System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(MyIdentity)
    Return MyPrincipal.IsInRole(GroupName)
End Function
```

Comment: I found this but I'm not good enough to convert it to vb.net.  Could someone help me out? 

`Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo") 
     strComputer = objSysInfo.ComputerName 
     Set objComputer = GetObject("LDAP://" & strComputer) objmemberOf = objComputer.GetEx("memberOf") 
     For Each objGroup in objmemberOf 
        groupCN = Split(objGroup, ",") 
        groupName = Mid(groupCN(0),4) 
        Next Select Case groupName 
     Case "TestGroup" 
         Wscript.Echo groupName 
     Case Else  
         Wscript.Echo "" 
     End Select`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to check AD group membership for a computer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126060/is-there-a-way-to-check-ad-group-membership-for-a-computer)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Function IsInGroup(PCName As String, groupName As String) As Boolean
      Dim vUsuario As New NTAccount(PCName & "$")
      Dim sid As SecurityIdentifier = vUsuario.Translate(GetType(SecurityIdentifier))

      Using vRootDSE As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://rootDSE")
         Using vSearcher As New DirectorySearcher(New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + CStr(vRootDSE.Properties("defaultNamingContext")(0))), "(objectSID=" & sid.ToString() & ")", New String() {"memberOf"}, SearchScope.Subtree)
            Dim src As SearchResultCollection = vSearcher.FindAll()

            Dim memberOf As ResultPropertyValueCollection = src(0).Properties("memberOf")
            For i As Integer = 0 To memberOf.Count - 1
               'Debug.Print(memberOf(i).ToString())

               ' I don't really like this approach, but it's quick to write ;)
               If memberOf(i).ToString().Contains("=" & groupName & ",") Then
                  Return True
               End If
            Next

         End Using

      End Using

      Return False
   End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the CURRENT PC then it's a bit easier.

```
    Function Is_CurrentPC_InADGroup(groupName As String) As Boolean
        if groupName = "" then Return True
        Using context = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERDOMAIN"))
            Dim principal = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, Environment.MachineName)
            Dim groups = principal.GetGroups()

            For Each group In groups
                If group.ToString = groupName Then Return True
            Next
        End Using
        Return False
    End Function
```